# Могу ли я вывести несколько PickeView на одном UIViewController?

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Могу ли я вывести несколько PickeView на одном UIViewController?

Comment: вы можете вывести несколько PickerView на одном UIViewController

Comment: Спасибо. Буду учиться завтра.

Comment: вы их хотите одновременно вывести?

Answer (score 0):

вы можете вывести несколько PickerView на одном UIViewController